# Increase frame rate and decrease duration of video using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution, frame-rate, duration

Please help me out. I have a video of 0.04 frame rate and 02:46:40 duration, and I want to increase frame rate to 25fps and decrease duration to 10s-13s. I have used these commands for fps and speed respectively:

1. ffmpeg -i input.avi -r 25 output.avi
2. ffmpeg -i output.avi -vf "setpts=0.001*PTS" output1.avi

But the final result output1.avi has distortion in it. How can I achieve my required fps and duration without any loss in my video quality?

Comment: This may help: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help. You totally saved me.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad to help.